# "Bad packet length xxx" when listing some sFTP directories only using SSH.NET C# library

Tags: c#, ssh, sftp

I get an error "bad packet length xxxxx" when retrieving some sFTP sub directory listings. My connection is successful. FileZilla ftp client (default settings) has exact same issue with same dir's, but CoreFTP Lite (default settings) can list all dir's easily.  If I move out a few files then I can list the sub directory's contents.

I heard it *may* because the sFTP server allows BOM as optional or something...

Are there any workarounds with SSH.NET C# library (latest version from https://sshnet.codeplex.com/).

```
foreach (var d in sftp.ConnectionInfo.Encryptions.Where(p => p.Key != "aes256-cbc").ToList())
    sftp.ConnectionInfo.Encryptions.Remove(d.Key);   // remove all Encryptions but the one listed above

sftp.ConnectionInfo.Encoding = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.ASCII;
sftp.Connect();  
var files = sftp.ListDirectory("/SubDirectory");  // Error Here
```

**EDIT :**  Am connecting to secure FTP server: (SSH-2.01.36 Globalscape)

Comment: I can get a directory listing using FileZilla if there are 250 files ore less.  I can get a directory listing if using c# SSH.NET library if there are 235 files or less... hmmm